# No "Browse Server" Button in CKEditor with KCFinder

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to integrate KCFinder in CKEditor in my Symfony2 Project.

I succeeded in showing CKEditor for my textarea field but I can't see the "Browse Server" Button in the image properties window.

However KCFinder works great in standalone mode (in accessing the kcfinder/browse.php file with Chrome)

In the ckeditor folder here is my config.js file:

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2003-2012, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
*/

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/Symfony/web/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/Symfony/web/kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/Symfony/web/kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/Symfony/web/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/Symfony/web/kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/Symfony/web/kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';
};
```

It's working in Firefox and not in Chrome? Why?

Comment: @Cœur Done :) .

Answer (score 0):

They fixed the problem but not in the compressed js file apparently... I used ckeditor_source.js instead and it works great !